# How to check if an Android in-app purchase is a test or regular purchase?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

Is there a way to programmatically check if a purchase is a test purchase or a regular one?

When you attempt a test purchase, Google notifies you that this is a test purchase and that you will not be charged for it. Is there a way to get that information in code?

Comment: The SKU you use for test purchase..shows that it is a test purchase

Comment: android.test.purchased this shows it is a test purchase..

Comment: That is for static purchases only. What if we have a regular purchase only that it's made with an account listed as a tester account. In that case a valid purchase is made, but Google does notify the user in the prompt, that it's a test purchase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it too much, unfortunately there is no way to get this information from Google on an Android application for now. If you are doing regular purchase with a tester account, all responses you got from Google apis are same with a non tester account. So it is impossible to differentiate it.